# Guice Method Interceptor Not Working

Tags: java, aop, guice

Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface PublishMetric {
}
```

Interceptor

```
public class PublishMetricInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
  @Override
  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("invoked");
    return methodInvocation.proceed();
  }
}
```

Guice Module

```
public class MetricsModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(PublishMetric.class), new PublishMetricInterceptor());
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  public Dummy getDummy(Client client) {
    return new Dummy(client);
  }
}
```

Usage

```
public class Dummy {
  private final Client client;

  @Inject
  public Dummy(final Client client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  @PublishMetric
  public String something() {
    System.out.println("something");
  }
}
```

I am not sure why this interceptor is not working.
Guice AOP Wiki states that

> Instances must be created by Guice by an @Inject-annotated or no-argument constructor It is not possible to use method interception on instances that aren't constructed by Guice.

Does using @Provides annotation to create new Object considered an instance created by Guice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your quote ist true: "It is not possible to use method interception on instances that aren't constructed by Guice."

So since you are calling `new Dummy()` in the provides method, it won't work.

If you use

```
  bind(Dummy.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

it does.

Comment: Yes, you don't need an `@Provides` for the example you shared as Client is also a dependency that is injected, Guice will do that for you! Also, for the class to be a singleton, you can slap the `@Singleton` annotation to the class declaration.

Comment: So can I instantiate Client dependency using @Provides since it doesn't require Method interceptor?

Comment: I am sorry, but your question is not clear to me. `Client` used in `Dummy` class is a dependency as you have annotated the `Dummy` class' constructor with `@Inject` and `Client client` is its only argument. Like any other dependency, you can specify the binding to for the type `Client` in your guice module, and this can be `@Provides` too.

Comment: this somehow feels counter intuitive to me, @Provides should be used when you have to define the constructed object returned by Guice, using bind shouldn't be more something for interface-class binding in a module?